# How to divide values from the same dimension in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculation, divide, calculated-field

I am trying to divide values from the same pill in Tableau. Per my screenshot, the pill is named "Animals" & the grouped values within that pill are dog, cat, hamster & horse.

How can I divide dog by cat? How can I divide hamster by horse? How I divide cat by hamster? etc.

How would I create a calculation to show the desired values?

[image]

Comment: could you please provide a sample output?

Comment: @AnilGoyal I have just added in another image to show the pill used

Comment: @AnilGoyal the expected outcome is for there to be a table of numbers that are divided by each other to create ratios & no, I do not use Tableau prep

Comment: See your expected results require pivoting of rows to columns, which is possible in Prep and not in tableau desktop/public.  If you want I could show you a method how to do it in data source application then ilke excel, sql?  By Expected results I mean what are the results in case of NULL/NA/division by 0.  All this you have to take care of

Comment: @AnilGoyal It can be done in Tableau Desktop, yes, please show me. & in case of Null, I would like it to be blank or 0

Comment: @AnilGoyal Oh I misunderstood your answer. It cannot be done in desktop?:(Is there any other way to divide values from the same dimension?

Comment: @AnilGoyal I am trying to replace the "Value" measure & it will not let me replace it with a count measure

Comment: @AnilGoyal I just replaced the image

Comment: @AnilGoyal Yes, that is

Comment: @AnilGoyal Everytime I replace "Value" with "Count" in the calculation, it does not work

Comment: @AnilGoyal Okay, once I do that, I get 0's for 1 column & all the other columns are blank

Comment: @AnilGoyal & I converted it to discrete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227210/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-j-a).

Answer (score 0):

Without the option of pivoting rows to columns available in Tableau Desktop, you have to manually create each of the desired ratio calculated field.

I have created a sample data by sampling 200 rows in a Programming language

Your created view is like this

[image]

Now create a calculated field for each of the desired ratio.  say `cat/dog` like this

```
ZN(SUM(IF [Animals] = "cat" then 1 else 0 END))/ 
ZN(SUM(IF [Animals] = "dog" then 1 else 0 END))
```

**Better use this field as discreet**

Add this field to view you'll get desired ratios

[image]

Comment: I have edited my answer completely.  It should now serve the purpose